# Is zombie state process really necessary in Linux?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, kernel

Zombie state is needed for the case when child process has exited, and in zombie state its exit value is saved until its parent process calls `wait()`.

But why not saving that exit value in the parent process descriptor when the child exits and immediately release the child's resources entirely?

Say for example we add to the process descriptor a stack of exit values of its childs.

Answer (score 2):

The key with fork -> wait model is not that you can get the exit status (and some other info), but that the pid of the process is kept in use until you wait for it. This means you can be confident nobody else will suddenly fork and get the same pid, which in certain cases has great value.

zombie itself really does not eat much. Everything heavy-weight is long freed and for practical purposes you can assume the overhead boils down to the struct describing the process and the slot in the pid table marked as used..

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process):

> When a process ends via exit, all of the memory and resources
>   associated with it are deallocated so they can be used by other
>   processes. However, the process's entry in the process table remains.

So there's no resource concern here. Now coming to your question,

> why not saving that exit value in the parent process descriptor when
>   the child exits

The reason is that the child can not access/modify the parent's process descriptor. It can only communicate with the parent.

So the child sends a `SIGCHLD` to the parent, and it's upto the parent to handle the signal.